# join two lists under condition

Tags: generics, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestSomethingRelatedToLINQ
{
    class Person : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        internal int personID;
        internal string PersonName;


        public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
        {
            return x.personID == y.personID;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
        {
            return obj.personID.GetHashCode();
        }


    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> list1 = new List<Person>{            
            new Person{personID = 1 , PersonName = "Ali"},
            new Person{personID = 2 , PersonName = "Ali1"},
            new Person{personID = 3 , PersonName = "Ali2"}            
            };

            List<Person> list2 = new List<Person>{            
            new Person{personID = 4 , PersonName = "Habib1"},
            new Person{personID = 2 , PersonName = "Habib2"},
            new Person{personID = 5 , PersonName = "Habib3"}            
            };           



        }
    }
}
```

I need to select all the elements in list1 , and all the element on list2 that doesn't have personID exists in List1 , then order the result by the personID

the new output should be like

```
1, Ali 
2, Ali1 
3, Ali2
4, Habib1
5, Habib3
```

any idea how to use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First call LINQ Concat, such that you append List 2 to List 1.

Then call LINQ Distinct, which will remove the entries that are duplicate (either the former or the latter).

[This site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94272/A-Generic-IEqualityComparer-for-Linq-Distinct) suggest classes you are used, you just implement the IEqualityComparer interface.

Comment: thanks a lot for this advice, I was mistaken in something after fixing it worked very well